# execution of sql query using 'concat' with 'where' is slow

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I've write a sql query like

```
select max(area_prefix) as called_area, location 
  from tabile_1 
  where '10012451373' like concat(area_prefix,'%')
```

To extract the `area_prefix` from the `table_1` but this query is too much slow when I put this query on live server then it is taking `85.0sec` to fetch the data, take `10012451373` as a `variable`.  Is there any other option to increase the performance .
The situation is, that we get a call from the different regions from all over the world , so we have to take out the `area_prefix` regarding that number so for that I've to see the whole `area_prefix`in the table to  tell the region from where the number belong this is where the `concat` keyword came into help but it is taking too much time when it put on a live server.
There is different table regarding regions.

```
CREATE TABLE `tariff_50` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `area_prefix` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `initial_increment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `default_increment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rate` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`area_prefix`),
  UNIQUE KEY `area_code` (`area_prefix`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=193542 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How can I achieve this by without using `CONCAT` keyword.

Comment: We need a bit more information. Can you add the table creation SQL, and the number or rows in your table, to your question?

Comment: If you use a function with a field of the table, them MySQL MUST read each ROW of them to see if the WHERE condition ist true: If the length of area_prefix is fix you can change your query like this: **select max(area_prefix) as called_area, location from tabile_1 where SUBSTRING('10012451373',1,4) =area_prefix**

Comment: No the length of `area_prefix` is not fixed.

Comment: You put SQL wildcard in right side of `like` operator which is wrong. it must be `concat(area_prefix,'%') like '10012451373'`.

Comment: no @AmirPashazadeh it is giving wrong result

Comment: What about `area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, length(area_prefix))`

Comment: Thanks @AmirPashazadeh but it is also not working

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh The wildcards go on the right-side of the `LIKE` operator, not the left.

Comment: how many rows are being fetched?

Comment: try `WHERE concat(area_prefix,'%') LIKE '%10012451373%'`

Comment: Perhaps a Full Text Search would be a better option here?

Comment: @connorg98 That doesn't work. It's the same suggestion Amir makes a few comments above, and the wildcard operator should appear to the right of the LIKE keyword. Furthermore, the issue is the speed of the query, not the logic of the query.

Comment: @JNevill Sorry sometimes i have to zoom my screen fully in haha i have terrible eyes, it could be a database issue then couldnt it?

Comment: @connorg98 Yes. I think it's a database issue, or really just a tuning issue. OP has to execute wildcard searches, and they are very slow. It's a difficult one to solve, I think. TheImpaler below has an approach that forces mysql to avoid the `Full Table Scan` which is the ultimate goal, but it's an ugly approach. I still feel like a `Full Text Search` may help, but I don't have enough experience with mysql and full text search to say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that this query is performing a Full Table Scan. You do have an index on the `area_prefix` column (since it's unique) but it's not being used by this query.

If you really want performance you would need to drastically change your query to make sure it uses the Index Seek operator while searching. The query shown below avoids using `LIKE` and forces the use of `=`. It's far uglier than the one you have, but it'll be very fast:

```
select max(area_prefix) from (
  select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 1)
  union select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 2)
  union select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 3)
  union select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 4)
  union select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 5)
  union select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 6)
  union select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 7)
  union select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 8)
  union select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 9)
  union select area_prefix, location from tariff_50 where area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 10)
) x;
```

I considered a maximum length of 10 characters for the area_prefix. If you have longer ones add more lines to this query.

I know it's ugly, but it's going to be blazing fast. :D

Comment: thanks @The_Impaler but this query is throwing error like `Every derived table must have its own alias.` so I've made some changes and it works `select max(area_prefix)as called_area,location from tarriff_50 WHERE area_prefix = substring('191698751373', 1, 1)OR  area_prefix = substring('191698751373', 1, 2) OR  area_prefix = substring('191698751373', 1, 3) OR  area_prefix = substring('191698751373', 1, 4) OR area_prefix = substring('191698751373', 1, 5) OR area_prefix = substring('191698751373', 1, 6) OR area_prefix = substring('191698751373', 1, 7)` assuming the `length` of `area_prefix` is 7

Comment: I just ran the SQL I posted (modified the table name) and ran well.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got as an answer:

```
select max(area_prefix) as called_area,location from tariff_50 
  WHERE area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 1)
  OR  area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 2) 
  OR  area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 3) 
  OR  area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 4) 
  OR area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 5) 
  OR area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 6) 
  OR area_prefix = substring('10012451373', 1, 7) assume `area_prefix` length 7
```